# Half the house has power - Stove, hotwater tank and dryer not working!

Tags: electrical

I have a 5 unit apartment building, but one unit is having a problem - which is only one side of the panel is working.  My electrician has checked the electrical panel inside the unit for connections and they appear to be good.  Then he went to check the breaker outside next to the meter and turned it on and off.  Then everything worked for couple of days and afterwards the same problem started again.  Now he's saying the breaker next to the meter is most likely not making good contact and needs to be replaced.  I talked to the city light and they said after changing the breaker and if the problem still existed then to call them so that they can come out and check their connections.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: So city light has replaced the breaker?

Comment: What make/model is the breaker at the meter-main, and what make and model is the meter-main for that matter?  Also, is this building set up with a unitary or modular multi-meter pack, or with individual meter bases fed from a gutter?

Comment: The breaker belongs to the owner, not the city light.  Monday my plan is to change the breaker near the meter and if that doesn't solve the problem, the city light said they would come out and check their connections.  I don't know the make and model now, I'll find out on Monday.  I believe this is a modular multi meter pack.

Answer (score 1):

Your electrician seems to be spot on. The fact that only one unit is having problems leads me to believe City Light's connections are good and the breaker after their connections for the problem unit is at fault. Why didn't your electrician replace that breaker when he examined it? 
If this was a breaker in the unit I'd suggest swapping it with another breaker in the panel and see if the problem followed. Since it's a main unit breaker you wouldn't want to do that and have the problem move to another unit and tick those people off.

Comment: Thanks Jack! We'll replace the breaker near the meter for this unit on Monday and see what happens.  Let you know if this works or not.  Thanks again!

Comment: Breaker was found to be faulty and replaced - all good now.  Thanks for the advice guys!

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not impossible that the other 4 units are having a problem also, and just not reporting it.  It took our 9-unit apartment days to figure out we had a lost neutral. Though presumably your electrician checked that out.

I am surprised, though, that the unit's main breaker at the meter would be having poor contact.  Given the stove is 40-50A, hot water is 30A and dryer is 30A, it can't possibly be a 30A or 60A service; must be 100A or more.  Typically in 100A-per-unit multiple meter setups, the "breaker next to the meter" *bolts down*, which precludes poor contact issues.  Now, some are plug-on types that clip on to bus stabs, and have a boltdown kit per NEC: those are quite cheap to swap - $38 for a 100A breaker. They can have contact issues, but it's easy and safe to pull one, and visually inspect the breaker bottom and bus stabs for arcing damage.  At $38 it makes sense to "throw parts at it" rather than have another service call.

Comment: Yeah, we are going to replace the breaker and go from there.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: It could also be a fault *internal* to the breaker, which'd be consistent with the off-on cycle causing the problem to go away for a couple of days